# Ошибка require(...).jsdom is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

При написании кода возникла такая ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем она может быть связана и какие варианты ее исправить?
Вот сам код:

```
const $ = require('jQuery');
 let main = function () {
"use strict";
$(".text-input button").on("click", function (event) {
    console.log("Нажата кнопка «=»");
    let $newInput = $("<p>").text($(".text-input input").val());
    $(".text-input").append($newInput);
});
$.getJSON("adr.json", function (adr) {
    // Выводим данные в консоль
    console.log(adr);
}); }; $(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Возможно, у вас несоответствие версий, похоже на использование старого API jsdom при установленном новом. См. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357864/ и https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Comment: Может помочь, если снесёте node_modules и переустановите библиотеку с последними зависимостями.